# Batch changing background colour

Tags: batch-file

It there a way in batch to change the background from black to blue. It must not change the default just for the window that is been run. so if i launch cmd later then it will be the default. If any one can help then thanks.

Comment: like `color 1e`? Just put it into the batch file or use google for other colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
color 3f
```

This changes the current background color.

Comment: Do `help color` in the command prompt and look at the help to see other color options.

Comment: This also changes the foreground color to white